# jQuery .submit() not working after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, request, submit

I want to submit a form if a condition is true. I tried with firebug, but there aren't any form submitted. I don't know why.

```
function test(){
   $.post('verify.php', { myID : '15' },
   function(data){
      if(data != 'OK') alert('WRONG !');
      else $('#my_form').submit();
   });
}
```

The condition is verified but the form "my_form" doesn't get submitted. There are no error in firebug console.

**EDIT:**

```
<form action='' method='post' id='my_form'>
   <input type='text' name='abc' />
   <input type='button' name='submit' value='Submit' onClick='test();' />
</form>
```

Comment: What does the response look like in Firebug?

Comment: Can we see your `<form>` tag while we're at it?

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault()
```

and

```
action="#"
```

might be what you're missing?

Answer (score 0):

When the POST request to your verify.php is unsuccessful (not 200 HTTP code in answer, and something like 404), the code in function doesn't executing.
If POST to verify.php was successful (200 code) then the problem is in another part of app: `$('#my_form').submit()`  should work in any case if form exists and ok. But, your form is NOT ok! 'action' attribute should not be empty. Try set action='#'.